# Datatable com JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery-datatables

Estou fazendo uma datatable com retorno do ajax.

```js
$.getJSON("sql.php?operacao=usuario_lista&excluidos=false", function (data) {
    alert(data.users);

    $('#tabusuarios').DataTable({
        "aaData": data.users,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "ID" },
            { "mDataProp": "NOME" },
            { "mDataProp": "USUARIO" }
        ]
    });
});
```

O meu JSON retorna:

```js
{
    "users": [
        {
            "ID": "89",
            "NOME": "aaabbbb",
            "USUARIO": "a.b",
            "DTNASC": "2017-01-01",
            "NUM": "112233"
        },
        {
            "ID": "76",
            "NOME": "Bruno Pereira",
            "USUARIO": "brunopereira",
            "DTNASC": "2011-01-01",
            "NUM": "11"
        }
    ]
}
```

Mas ele da o erro:

> DataTables warning: table id=tabusuarios - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

E não popula a table..

Comment: Já tentou criar sua tabela baseada nos exemplos do datatables.net? Existe outras formas de ler um json, veja [aqui (ajax custom_data_property)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html).

Comment: ja tentei sim Florida....ele simplesmente nao carrega nada...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33367053/1432957), você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabusuarios').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "sql.php?operacao=usuario_lista&excluidos=false",
            dataSrc : ''
        },
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "ID"
        }, {
            "data" : "NOME"
        }, {
            "data" : "USUARIO"
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: eu fiz como vc colocou...agora nao da erros, mas a tabela fica como "No data available in table", sendo que o ajax retornou dados

Comment: mas vi agora que no que mencionaram acima, com usando "https://api.myjson.com/bins/14t4g" ele vai...  Parece que deve haver algum problema com o jeito que eu to retornando meu json...

Comment: O resultado do seu `JSON` está com o `content-type` correto? Ou está voltando um `TXT`?

Comment: Marcelo eu descobri o que eh..no retorno do meu sql.php eu fazia: echo '{"users":'.json_encode($result).'}'; ...Quando eu tirei essa parte do users e retornei direto o json_encode($result) ele foi....

Comment: Mas estou usando seu codigo tambem...Obrigado a voce e a todos que responderam! Valews!!!! :)

Comment: Eu iria comentar exatamente isso. Tenta alterar a coluna de `data` para `data.users`

Comment: mas ai no seu exemplo eu colocaria aonde o data.users? na parte de columns?

Comment: isso, tenta algo como `"data.users" : "ID"`

Comment: saquei..muito obrigado!